# How to error check when entering a float in c?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I have a program that prompts the user for an integer that is not negative or character. I want to prompt the user for a float instead. How do i do this?

```
do {
    printf("Enter a number.\n");  
} while(((scanf("%d%c", &x1, &term) != 2 || term != '\n') 
          && reset_stdin()) || x1 < 1);

int reset_stdin()
{
    while (getchar()!='\n');
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `scanf` with a `float`, just use the `"%f"` format specifier.

```
float input;
scanf("%f", &input);
```